# Why can't I use a cname/alias in the permissions table?

Tags: mysql, permissions, alias

At work we have a usual setup with web server(apache) and database server(mysql). From time to time there is the need to migrate the web stuff to a new server. Lets say their a records are `dull` and `shiny` with cname `www` for `dull`, which we want to reassign to `shiny`, when `shiny` is set and done.

We - trying to be good admins - want to restrict database access as much as possible and only gave access to `'dbuser'@'dull'`. But what we really want is to give access to `'dbuser'@'www'`, so that after reassigning the cname we don't need to alter the permissions.

I read that mysql does a reverse looup of the IP and then a lookup of the a record and will fail if anything in this process is fishy.

Why is there such a strict policy on this? Is there a reason why I can't use a cname in the permissions?

Bonus Question: What can I do to accomplish easy migration?

*Edit*: Split of bonus question

Comment: Ok. I should have split up the question and be more precise. The main question of the post is not the last question, but rather, why there is such a strict policy.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  If `dull` and `shiny` don't change, leave both in effect?...

```
GRANT ... TO dbuser@dull ...;
GRANT ... TO dbuser@shiny ...;
```

But, beware, this could leave the "production" system accessible to "QA".  (Assuming that is really what you are doing.)

Plan B:  A simple script (after transferring):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host = 'shiny' WHERE host = 'dull';
```

But, again, beware -- If the script fails to be run successfully, QA could be hitting production.

Plan C:  Well, there is likely to be some other trick.

Comment: Question (probably dumb): what does QA stand for? These two option are exactly what we came up with, but are very unsatified with.

Comment: Quality Assurance.  The folks that test your product before going 'live'.  "Replication" might be a tool to use.  Can you elaborate on why you "migrate"?

Comment: By "migrate" I mean we set up a new server with an updated version of the linux distribution (ubuntu/debian) and start at plane zero. Then we configure it and sync the content, which is directly on the web server (no ntework mounts etc.).

Comment: OK.  No new tricks come to mind.

Comment: Thanks again. For my scenario I guess Plan A works best.